# Using jquery to find text based on certain color in a table

Tags: jquery

```js
$('tr:not(:first) td:first-child').filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
 }).each(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Project</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1718
            </td>
            <td>
                bid
            </td>
            <td>
               user1
            </td>
            <td>
                date
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1718
            </td>
            <td>
                design
            </td>
            <td>
               user2
            </td>
            <td>
                date
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1720
            </td>
            <td>
                design
            </td>
            <td>
               user3
            </td>
            <td>
                1722
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                1720
            </td>
            <td>
                construction
            </td>
            <td>
               user4
            </td>
            <td>
                1722
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <p style="color:red">17290</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                construction
            </td>
            <td>
               user5
            </td>
            <td>
                1722
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So basically I have a table and I want to find cells in the first column with a specific text color (black). However, my code is not working. In this sample table, it's highlighting all the cells with different colors rather than just black....Also, at the moment I have it highlighting the text with black color but would it be possible to insert a new blank row above it instead??

Comment: Please share what you have done

Comment: Sorry I thought it was in there! but i added it now

Comment: The red color is not on the `<td>` but on a child `<p>` . Not clear what expected behavior is for that case. Would also be much cleaner doing this with classes. Also note that `color` may return `rgba` in some browsers not `rgb`

Comment: It will work if you remove the `<p>` element.

Comment: @Daniel wow thanks I dont know why I didn't see that..but thank you! Also would you know how to go about inserting a blank row then instead of highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment the `p` tag was at fault for the target.

To insert a new empty row you would have to find the parent of the `td` element (the `tr` element) and add a new empty `tr` element before it with at least one `td` element.

This can be done with the following jQuery

```
$(this).parent().before('<tr><td></td></tr>');
```

#### Example

```js
$('tr:not(:first) td:first-child').filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
 }).each(function() {  
  $(this).parent().before('<tr><td></td></tr>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Project</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1718
            </td>
            <td>
                bid
            </td>
            <td>
               user1
            </td>
            <td>
                date
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1718
            </td>
            <td>
                design
            </td>
            <td>
               user2
            </td>
            <td>
                date
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1720
            </td>
            <td>
                design
            </td>
            <td>
               user3
            </td>
            <td>
                1722
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                1720
            </td>
            <td>
                construction
            </td>
            <td>
               user4
            </td>
            <td>
                1722
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="color:red">17290
            </td>
            <td>
                construction
            </td>
            <td>
               user5
            </td>
            <td>
                1722
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the text on the `td` not in a `<p>`.

Try this code it can resolve your problem.

```js
$('tr:not(:first) td:first-child').filter(function() {
   if($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'){
     $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
   }else{
    $(this).css('background-color', 'none');
   }
 });
```

```css
#differente{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Project</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1718
            </td>
            <td>
                bid
            </td>
            <td>
               user1
            </td>
            <td>
                date
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1718
            </td>
            <td>
                design
            </td>
            <td>
               user2
            </td>
            <td>
                date
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1720
            </td>
            <td>
                design
            </td>
            <td>
               user3
            </td>
            <td>
                1722
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                1720
            </td>
            <td>
                construction
            </td>
            <td>
               user4
            </td>
            <td>
                1722
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td id="differente">
                17290
            </td>
            <td>
                construction
            </td>
            <td>
               user5
            </td>
            <td>
                1722
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Best to use a dummy element to apply color to...then retrieve color value from it and compare to that. Not all browsers will return `rgb` as computed style

Comment: I don't mean setting with css rule...can use rgb to set ... it is getting computed style from element that may differ browser to browser

Comment: @N.Malloul yes i got that now! would you be able to help me insert a new row now instead of highlighting the cells?

Comment: You want to insert a new row at the end of the table?